# Locally declared variable takes up global variable space in dynamic memory/SRAM

Tags: ir, variables, memory, sram

I'm trying to make my Arduino Uno control the air conditioner by recording the raw IR signal of several of the AC remotes temperatures using AnalysisIR. However these IR codes are quite long (array with 343 items).

Declaring more than one IR code in a variable shows me the error:
"Global variables use 2064 bytes (100%) of dynamic memory, leaving -16 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes."

However, as seen in my code, I have declared the IR codes locally in a separate function to send them to the air conditioner. I don't understand why i get the error saying the global variables are taking up too much dynamic memory.

Isn't the space taken up by the local variable supposed to be freed up from the SRAM once the functions runs because I have declared the variable locally?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>


IRsend irsend;


int khz = 38;

void send23()
{

  unsigned int irSignal[]= {9048, 4496, 620, 1636, 620, 1636, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 524, 620, 532, 620, 1648, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 1644, 620, 520, 620, 528, 616, 528, 620, 532, 624, 516, 620, 1636, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 616, 536, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 1648, 620, 1656, 620, 1656, 616, 524, 620, 508, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 624, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 516, 616, 520, 624, 524, 620, 524, 620, 532, 620, 504, 620, 7956, 616, 512, 620, 1640, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 620, 528, 624, 1644, 620, 1636, 616, 1640, 624, 1640, 620, 1648, 616, 528, 620, 1652, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 512, 620, 512, 620, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 616, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 516, 620, 516, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 512, 620, 516, 624, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 1640, 624, 1640, 624, 1648, 620, 524, 624, 1656, 624, 1624, 624, 7952, 616, 512, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 624, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 628, 516, 624, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 628, 512, 624, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 520, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 624, 500, 608};
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal, sizeof(irSignal) / sizeof(irSignal[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
}

void send22()
{

  unsigned int irSignal[]=  {8988, 4548, 572, 1688, 572, 1688, 600, 532, 572, 568, 572, 572, 576, 572, 572, 580, 572, 1724, 544, 556, 576, 1684, 600, 1660, 608, 532, 604, 540, 608, 540, 600, 548, 608, 536, 604, 1652, 608, 520, 616, 524, 608, 532, 612, 532, 612, 532, 620, 532, 616, 524, 620, 512, 616, 1644, 624, 508, 628, 516, 624, 520, 628, 1676, 596, 1648, 632, 508, 632, 500, 632, 500, 632, 504, 636, 504, 636, 512, 628, 516, 632, 524, 628, 508, 636, 496, 632, 504, 628, 508, 632, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 516, 632, 496, 628, 7948, 628, 500, 632, 1656, 600, 508, 628, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 1672, 600, 1672, 600, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 632, 512, 628, 512, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 476, 656, 480, 632, 508, 632, 516, 632, 512, 656, 496, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 656, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 632, 520, 656, 484, 656, 1632, 624, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 1620, 652, 488, 656, 1656, 600, 1648, 604, 7948, 656, 472, 656, 476, 660, 480, 632, 508, 656, 488, 652, 496, 656, 492, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 1608, 628, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 656, 496, 656, 484, 632, 496, 656, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 656, 496, 628, 508, 660, 472, 656, 480, 656, 480, 652, 488, 656, 488, 656, 492, 652, 496, 660, 484, 656, 472, 632, 504, 652, 484, 652, 1644, 624, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 628, 500, 664, 468, 656, 480, 656, 488, 652, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 652, 476, 656, 1632, 624, 484, 652, 1644, 620, 492, 656, 488, 628, 524, 652, 472, 608};
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal, sizeof(irSignal) / sizeof(irSignal[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  delay(2000);
  send23();
  delay(2000);
  send22();
}

void loop() {

}
```

EDIT 05/07:

Here is my new code with the use of PROGMEM.

As you can see, i have initialized the progmem arrays globally at the top of the program. When i do this, my SRAM is not full anymore but sendraw in the functions does not work anymore.

Weirdly however, when i declare the progmem variable INSIDE the send23() function (IN COMMENTS), the sendraw works! But the variable takes up space in the SRAM again and it says that Global variables have used 100% of dynamic memory.

Why does this happen and what can i do to work around it?

PROGMEM updated code:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>

const unsigned int irSignal23[] PROGMEM = {9048, 4496, 620, 1636, 620, 1636, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 524, 620, 532, 620, 1648, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 1644, 620, 520, 620, 528, 616, 528, 620, 532, 624, 516, 620, 1636, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 616, 536, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 1648, 620, 1656, 620, 1656, 616, 524, 620, 508, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 624, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 516, 616, 520, 624, 524, 620, 524, 620, 532, 620, 504, 620, 7956, 616, 512, 620, 1640, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 620, 528, 624, 1644, 620, 1636, 616, 1640, 624, 1640, 620, 1648, 616, 528, 620, 1652, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 512, 620, 512, 620, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 616, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 516, 620, 516, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 512, 620, 516, 624, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 1640, 624, 1640, 624, 1648, 620, 524, 624, 1656, 624, 1624, 624, 7952, 616, 512, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 624, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 628, 516, 624, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 628, 512, 624, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 520, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 624, 500, 608};
const unsigned int irSignal22[] PROGMEM = {8988, 4548, 572, 1688, 572, 1688, 600, 532, 572, 568, 572, 572, 576, 572, 572, 580, 572, 1724, 544, 556, 576, 1684, 600, 1660, 608, 532, 604, 540, 608, 540, 600, 548, 608, 536, 604, 1652, 608, 520, 616, 524, 608, 532, 612, 532, 612, 532, 620, 532, 616, 524, 620, 512, 616, 1644, 624, 508, 628, 516, 624, 520, 628, 1676, 596, 1648, 632, 508, 632, 500, 632, 500, 632, 504, 636, 504, 636, 512, 628, 516, 632, 524, 628, 508, 636, 496, 632, 504, 628, 508, 632, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 516, 632, 496, 628, 7948, 628, 500, 632, 1656, 600, 508, 628, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 1672, 600, 1672, 600, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 632, 512, 628, 512, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 476, 656, 480, 632, 508, 632, 516, 632, 512, 656, 496, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 656, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 632, 520, 656, 484, 656, 1632, 624, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 1620, 652, 488, 656, 1656, 600, 1648, 604, 7948, 656, 472, 656, 476, 660, 480, 632, 508, 656, 488, 652, 496, 656, 492, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 1608, 628, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 656, 496, 656, 484, 632, 496, 656, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 656, 496, 628, 508, 660, 472, 656, 480, 656, 480, 652, 488, 656, 488, 656, 492, 652, 496, 660, 484, 656, 472, 632, 504, 652, 484, 652, 1644, 624, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 628, 500, 664, 468, 656, 480, 656, 488, 652, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 652, 476, 656, 1632, 624, 484, 652, 1644, 620, 492, 656, 488, 628, 524, 652, 472, 608};
const unsigned int irSignal21[] PROGMEM = {9044, 4496, 624, 1628, 628, 1592, 668, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 500, 628, 1632, 624, 1636, 628, 512, 628, 520, 628, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 1628, 628, 512, 620, 512, 624, 516, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 500, 632, 1628, 628, 512, 628, 512, 628, 1644, 628, 520, 628, 1648, 628, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 628, 508, 632, 508, 628, 516, 632, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 500, 624, 7948, 628, 504, 628, 1628, 628, 512, 624, 516, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 1636, 628, 504, 624, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 1640, 628, 1648, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 500, 632, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 624, 520, 624, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 624, 516, 628, 512, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 628, 1624, 628, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 1644, 628, 1648, 628, 1620, 628, 7944, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 512, 624, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 508, 632, 508, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 632, 512, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 628, 508, 628, 1640, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 512, 628, 504, 628, 1632, 624, 512, 628, 1640, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 492, 612};

IRsend irsend;

int khz = 38;

void send23()
{

//  const unsigned int irSignal23[] PROGMEM = {9048, 4496, 620, 1636, 620, 1636, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 524, 620, 532, 620, 1648, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 1644, 620, 520, 620, 528, 616, 528, 620, 532, 624, 516, 620, 1636, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 616, 536, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 1640, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 1648, 620, 1656, 620, 1656, 616, 524, 620, 508, 620, 516, 616, 520, 620, 520, 624, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 516, 616, 520, 624, 524, 620, 524, 620, 532, 620, 504, 620, 7956, 616, 512, 620, 1640, 616, 520, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 528, 620, 528, 624, 1644, 620, 1636, 616, 1640, 624, 1640, 620, 1648, 616, 528, 620, 1652, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 512, 620, 512, 620, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 616, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 520, 620, 528, 620, 532, 620, 520, 620, 508, 620, 516, 620, 516, 620, 520, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 620, 512, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 512, 620, 516, 624, 516, 620, 524, 620, 524, 624, 528, 620, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 1640, 624, 1640, 624, 1648, 620, 524, 624, 1656, 624, 1624, 624, 7952, 616, 512, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 624, 520, 624, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 524, 628, 516, 624, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 628, 512, 624, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 620, 520, 620, 524, 624, 520, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 624, 512, 624, 516, 624, 520, 624, 524, 624, 528, 624, 516, 620, 508, 624, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 1640, 624, 520, 624, 524, 620, 528, 624, 500, 608};
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal23, sizeof(irSignal23) / sizeof(irSignal23[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
}

void send22()
{
//  const unsigned int irSignal22[] PROGMEM = {8988, 4548, 572, 1688, 572, 1688, 600, 532, 572, 568, 572, 572, 576, 572, 572, 580, 572, 1724, 544, 556, 576, 1684, 600, 1660, 608, 532, 604, 540, 608, 540, 600, 548, 608, 536, 604, 1652, 608, 520, 616, 524, 608, 532, 612, 532, 612, 532, 620, 532, 616, 524, 620, 512, 616, 1644, 624, 508, 628, 516, 624, 520, 628, 1676, 596, 1648, 632, 508, 632, 500, 632, 500, 632, 504, 636, 504, 636, 512, 628, 516, 632, 524, 628, 508, 636, 496, 632, 504, 628, 508, 632, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 516, 632, 496, 628, 7948, 628, 500, 632, 1656, 600, 508, 628, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 1672, 600, 1672, 600, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 632, 512, 628, 512, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 476, 656, 480, 632, 508, 632, 516, 632, 512, 656, 496, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 656, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 632, 520, 656, 484, 656, 1632, 624, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 1620, 652, 488, 656, 1656, 600, 1648, 604, 7948, 656, 472, 656, 476, 660, 480, 632, 508, 656, 488, 652, 496, 656, 492, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 1608, 628, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 656, 496, 656, 484, 632, 496, 656, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 656, 496, 628, 508, 660, 472, 656, 480, 656, 480, 652, 488, 656, 488, 656, 492, 652, 496, 660, 484, 656, 472, 632, 504, 652, 484, 652, 1644, 624, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 628, 500, 664, 468, 656, 480, 656, 488, 652, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 652, 476, 656, 1632, 624, 484, 652, 1644, 620, 492, 656, 488, 628, 524, 652, 472, 608};
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal22, sizeof(irSignal22) / sizeof(irSignal22[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
}

void send21()
{
//  const unsigned int irSignal21[] PROGMEM = {9044, 4496, 624, 1628, 628, 1592, 668, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 500, 628, 1632, 624, 1636, 628, 512, 628, 520, 628, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 1628, 628, 512, 620, 512, 624, 516, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 500, 632, 1628, 628, 512, 628, 512, 628, 1644, 628, 520, 628, 1648, 628, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 628, 508, 632, 508, 628, 516, 632, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 500, 624, 7948, 628, 504, 628, 1628, 628, 512, 624, 516, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 1636, 628, 504, 624, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 1640, 628, 1648, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 516, 628, 524, 628, 512, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 500, 632, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 624, 520, 624, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 624, 516, 628, 512, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 628, 1624, 628, 1632, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 1644, 628, 1648, 628, 1620, 628, 7944, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 512, 624, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 628, 512, 628, 504, 624, 1636, 624, 508, 632, 508, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 632, 512, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 628, 500, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 512, 628, 504, 624, 508, 628, 508, 628, 1640, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 516, 624, 504, 628, 504, 628, 508, 628, 512, 628, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 624, 512, 628, 504, 628, 1632, 624, 512, 628, 1640, 624, 516, 628, 520, 628, 524, 628, 492, 612};
  irsend.sendRaw(irSignal21, sizeof(irSignal21) / sizeof(irSignal21[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  send23();
  Serial.println("done");
  delay(4000);
  send22();
  Serial.println("done");
  delay(4000);
  send21();
  Serial.println("done");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: The compiler can probably not be fooled that easy. I don't know how the compiler deals with it, perhaps someone else knows the answer. Do you really need integers? or is is a few different timings that could be put into a byte? I think you need an arduino board with more memory. Arrays of constant data belong in progmem: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Comment: use PROGMEM https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Comment: I tried using PROGMEM as well. However, if the const PROGMEM variable is declared inside the 'loop' function, it still takes up space in the SRAM. If the const PROGMEM variable is declared outside any function (globally), it no longer takes up space in the SRAM but the irRemote "sendRaw function no longer works."

Comment: make the PROGMEM array global and copy it to RAM in the function

Comment: Can you point me on how to copy the global PROGMEM array into my RAM during the functions execution?

Comment: `memArr[i] = pgm_read_word_near(progmemArr[i]);`

Answer (score 6):

> Isn't the space taken up by the local variable supposed to be freed up
>   from the SRAM once the functions runs because I have declared the
>   variable locally?

This is correct. The local arrays you have take up RAM only while the
corresponding function is executing. They do not consume any static RAM
(i.e. .data and .bss, what the Arduino IDE improperly calls “Global
variables”).

The problem is not the arrays themselves, but rather the data used to
initialize them. As an experiment, you can try to change the array
definitions as follows:

```c++
unsigned int irSignal[343];
```

You will see the memory consumption reported by the IDE drop by
4×343 bytes. The local arrays are still there. They use RAM (from
the stack) when the functions execute. Only you have removed the
matching initializers.

I disassembled a slightly modified copy of your program just to see how
the compiler handles it. I will not post the assembly code here, as I
guess not many people here are fluent in AVR assembly. Instead, I will
attempt to translate the assembly back to C in the most straightforward
way. The compiler interpreted the function `send23()` as follows:

```c++
static const unsigned int anonymous_array_1[343] = {9048, ...};

void send23()
{
    unsigned int irSignal[343];
    for (int i = 0; i < 343; i++)
        irSignal[i] = anonymous_array_1[i];
    irsend.sendRaw(irSignal, 343, khz);
}
```

What is taking up static RAM is not the local arrays, it's the global
anonymous arrays that hold the initialization data. You may notice that
making the arrays local has actually worsened the problem: while
`send23()` executes, you have *two copies* of the data in RAM.

The solution, as Jot and Juraj said in comments, is to put the arrays in
`PROGMEM`. If it doesn't work, then you have a bug. You should fix the
bug instead of trying to avoid `PROGMEM`.

Comment: Yes I have tried the progmem approach. Please see my edit on the post. I am guessing what i need to do now is to figure out how to copy the progmem variable into ram when the function runs? Perhaps that is why the send raw function is not working.

Comment: This is now very different from your original question. You should ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You must declare the array in global space or `static`, and make sure the function you pass the buffer pointer to knows it is in PROGMEM.

```
void send22()
{

  static unsigned int irSignal[] PROGMEM=  {8988, 4548, 572, 1688, 572, 1688, 600, 532, 572, 568, 572, 572, 576, 572, 572, 580, 572, 1724, 544, 556, 576, 1684, 600, 1660, 608, 532, 604, 540, 608, 540, 600, 548, 608, 536, 604, 1652, 608, 520, 616, 524, 608, 532, 612, 532, 612, 532, 620, 532, 616, 524, 620, 512, 616, 1644, 624, 508, 628, 516, 624, 520, 628, 1676, 596, 1648, 632, 508, 632, 500, 632, 500, 632, 504, 636, 504, 636, 512, 628, 516, 632, 524, 628, 508, 636, 496, 632, 504, 628, 508, 632, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 516, 632, 496, 628, 7948, 628, 500, 632, 1656, 600, 508, 628, 508, 632, 512, 632, 516, 632, 524, 628, 1636, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 1672, 600, 1672, 600, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 632, 512, 628, 512, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 496, 632, 504, 632, 504, 632, 508, 632, 516, 628, 520, 628, 520, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 476, 656, 480, 632, 508, 632, 516, 632, 512, 656, 496, 632, 508, 632, 500, 652, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 632, 520, 632, 508, 632, 500, 656, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 632, 520, 656, 484, 656, 1632, 624, 476, 632, 508, 656, 484, 656, 1620, 652, 488, 656, 1656, 600, 1648, 604, 7948, 656, 472, 656, 476, 660, 480, 632, 508, 656, 488, 652, 496, 656, 492, 656, 484, 632, 500, 656, 1608, 628, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 656, 492, 656, 496, 656, 484, 632, 496, 656, 480, 632, 504, 656, 484, 656, 488, 632, 516, 656, 496, 628, 508, 660, 472, 656, 480, 656, 480, 652, 488, 656, 488, 656, 492, 652, 496, 660, 484, 656, 472, 632, 504, 652, 484, 652, 1644, 624, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 628, 500, 664, 468, 656, 480, 656, 488, 652, 488, 656, 492, 656, 492, 632, 512, 652, 476, 656, 1632, 624, 484, 652, 1644, 620, 492, 656, 488, 628, 524, 652, 472, 608};
  irsend.sendRaw_P(irSignal, sizeof(irSignal) / sizeof(irSignal[0]), khz); 
  // _P postfix is often used to mark functions taking in PROGMEM pointers
}
```

You can adjust the library to allow it to take PROGMEM buffers, with a quick search for the implementation of `IRsend::sendRaw` it gave me:

```
void  IRsend::sendRaw (const unsigned int buf[],  unsigned int len,  unsigned int hz)
{
    // Set IR carrier frequency
    enableIROut(hz);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
        if (i & 1)  space(buf[i]) ;
        else        mark (buf[i]) ;
    }

    space(0);  // Always end with the LED off
}
```

To make it work with progmem you can create:

```
void  IRsend::sendRaw_P (const unsigned int buf[],  unsigned int len,  unsigned int hz)
{
    // Set IR carrier frequency
    enableIROut(hz);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
        unsigned int word = pgm_read_word_near(buf + i);
        if (i & 1)  space(word) ;
        else        mark (word) ;
    }

    space(0);  // Always end with the LED off
}
```

Comment: How should i proceed to edit the existing IRremote library?