# storage problem

Tags: arduino-uno, memory-usage, memory

I made a Arduino program to control my air conditioner(model:GREE Lomo) by PC.
I download IRremote library from [here](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote) for that.

```
#include "IRremote.h"

IRsend irsend;
int irPin = 3; // pin IR led

int khz = 38; // 38kHz carrier frequency for the NEC protocol

const unsigned int irSignalOn[] = {8972, 4492, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 636, 568, 640, 1664, 644, 560, 644,
                               560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 644,
                               1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1664, 644,
                               560, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 560, 644, 19980, 640, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640,
                               564, 644, 1660, 644, 560, 644, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564,
                               640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564,
                               640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 39972, 8976, 4496, 640, 1664, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640,
                               1668, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 1668, 640,
                               564, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1668, 636, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 644, 560, 644,
                               1668, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 19980, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640,
                               564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 636, 568, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 640, 1672, 636, 1664, 640,
                               564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 1692, 616,
                               1664, 640, 564, 640, 1664, 640, 39980, 8972, 4492, 644, 1664, 640, 568, 636, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 564,
                               640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 560, 644, 1664, 640, 1664, 644, 564, 640, 1668,
                               640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1660, 644, 1664, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1664, 640, 1664, 644, 1664,
                               644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 1668, 640, 560, 644, 19984, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640,
                               564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 560, 644, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564,
                               640, 1664, 640, 1668, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 568, 640, 560, 644, 1668, 640, 1664, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644
                              };

const unsigned int irSignalOff[] = {8996, 4496, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 564,
                                640, 1688, 616, 1692, 616, 568, 640, 568, 636, 1668, 640, 1688, 616, 1692, 616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 1692, 616,
                                568, 636, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 564, 640, 1692, 616, 568, 636, 564, 640, 1672, 636,
                                564, 644, 19980, 640, 568, 636, 1692, 616, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 572, 636, 564, 640, 568, 640, 564, 640,
                                568, 636, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 564, 640, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 568,
                                636, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 1692, 616, 39980, 8972, 4496, 640, 1688,
                                616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 636, 1692, 616, 564, 640, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 1692, 612,
                                568, 640, 564, 640, 1692, 612, 1692, 616, 1692, 616, 564, 640, 568, 640, 564, 640, 1692, 612, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 636, 568,
                                640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640, 1692, 612, 1692, 616, 568, 640, 564, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 19984, 640, 564, 640, 568, 640,
                                564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 644, 1688, 616, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636,
                                568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 1672, 636, 1692, 612, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1692, 612, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640,
                                564, 640, 1692, 616, 1668, 632, 568, 640, 39980, 8972, 4500, 640, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 1668, 640, 568,
                                636, 568, 640, 568, 636, 564, 640, 568, 636, 1692, 616, 1688, 616, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1668, 636, 1688, 620, 1692, 612, 568, 640, 564,
                                640, 564, 640, 1692, 612, 568, 640, 564, 644, 564, 640, 564, 640, 552, 652, 568, 640, 1688, 616, 1688, 616, 1692, 616, 564, 640, 568,
                                640, 1664, 640, 564, 640, 19988, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568,
                                636, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 568, 640, 564, 636, 568, 640, 568, 636, 568, 636, 568, 636, 568, 640, 1668, 636, 1692, 616, 568,
                                640, 564, 640, 564, 640, 568, 636, 568, 640, 564, 640, 1692, 616, 564, 640, 568, 636, 1692, 616
                               };

void setup() {
  pinMode(irPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char letter = Serial.read();
    if (letter == '1') {
      irsend.sendRaw(irSignalOn, sizeof(irSignalOn) / sizeof(irSignalOn[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
      Serial.println("ON");
    } else if (letter == '0') {
      irsend.sendRaw(irSignalOff, sizeof(irSignalOff) / sizeof(irSignalOff[0]), khz); //Note the approach used to automatically calculate the size of the array.
      Serial.println("OFF");
    }
  }
}
```

i got an error for arduino uno :
 Global variables use 2080 bytes (101%) of dynamic memory, leaving -32 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

how can i fix it?

EDIT 07/26:

I know with board like ATmega2560 problem will fix but I want use Arduino uno.

I tried to save my data at program memory but I don't know how to read that.

Comment: Search “PROGMEM”.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54150/locally-declared-variable-takes-up-global-variable-space-in-dynamic-memory-sram

Comment: what make and model of air conditioner?

Comment: the signal data could be greatly reduced .... https://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol

Comment: Re “I don't know how to read that”: 1. Search the Web for “Arduino PROGMEM”, or “AVR PROGMEM”. 2. Carefully read the resources you find, and **try for yourself**. 3. If you still can't after having given a genuine effort, then post here **another** question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to move the tables into program memory (aka PROGMEM). Use the below:

```
const unsigned int irSignalOn[] PROGMEM = {
 ...
};
```

And modify the call to `sendRaw()` to `sendRaw_P()`.

```
irsend.sendRaw_P(irSignalOn, sizeof(irSignalOn) / sizeof(irSignalOn[0]), khz);
```

For more information see the library documentation.

Cheers!

Comment: i used shirriff's IRremote library and compiler don't find sendRaw_P function ?

Comment: @MortezaMirzai Please update your question with all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

**not an answer**

please try this

let me know if it turns on the A/C when you press `1`

```
#include "IRremote.h"

IRsend irsend;
int irPin = 3; // pin IR led

int khz = 38; // 38kHz carrier frequency for the NEC protocol


void setup() {
  pinMode(irPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char letter = Serial.read();
    if (letter == '1') {
      irsend.sendNEC(0x4A08D3052, 35);
      irsend.sendNEC(0x64040002,  32);
      irsend.sendNEC(0x4A08D3032, 35);
      irsend.sendNEC(0x0015888D,  32);
      irsend.sendNEC(0x4A08D3072, 35);
      irsend.sendNEC(0x00000C0C,  32);

      Serial.println("ON");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I test that but it don't work. (maybe my fault) and compiler give a warning.

Comment: that's it? .... `compiler give a warning`  .... nothing about the warning? .... do you want help or not?

Comment: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow] irsend.sendNEC(0x4A08D3052, 35);

Answer (score 0):

One can also jump to a Atmega1284P based board, with it's 16K of SRAM, 8x that of a '328P's 2K and 2x that of the Mega's 8K.  Dual hardware serial ports too if your project should need one.

Comment: or an esp8266 for cheaper and with 4X the ram and dozens of times the flash...

Comment: But limited to 3.3V operation, and I think much less current capability on the IO, if the project needs that.